# Are questions about choosing colors for the interior okay?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Suppose I want to paint a ceiling in my apartment and I need to choose paint color with some technical and more or less non-subjective requirements like "I have rather low ceiling, which colors to pick to not make it look lower?"

Are such questions on choosing colors for the interior with defined non-subjective requirements appropriate here?

Comment: Your example question here is borderline on topic, but the [question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/office-ceiling-painting) you are basing this question on was completely subjective and off topic. 
The site is more about the tools and techniques used for painting, not the specific colors.

Answer (score 8):

As phrased that seems reasonable to me.  No different than: "I want a countertop that can double as a cooling surface for baking pans".  Final choice is subjective, but completely answerable with a narrow set of options.

The only problem with color questions is when you start fading into more interior design aspects like trying to match drapes, or making a room "pop".  I can see where a question like this might be a gateway to fade that direction, but I don't think we have the audience for it anyway.

My litmus test is something like:  Would a GC, plumber, electrician, carpenter, etc be able to answer this authoritatively?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in that context, it is fine (as Steve noted) -- but this is a slippery slope, so I would be very clear about the technical reasons for asking about paint colors.

We definitely don't want new users getting the idea that "what color should I paint my bedroom?" is somehow on topic..